# Powershell editing multiple password protected Word files

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I located the below Powershell code that works excellently for editing multiple Word docs, however when the docs are password protected it fails.

1. I know the password (which is the same for all files).
2. I have modified line 86 to pass in a password variable (requested from user
   earlier in the script).

   086 Function processDoc ($pass) {
3. Line 87 then uses the variable in what I understand (I could be wrong) to be the [correct format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/documents-open-method-word).

   087 $doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName, $null, $false, $null, $pass, $null, $null, $pass)
4. I invoke line 96 passing in the password variable.

   096   $countr = processDoc($passwd)

It does not work and I don't know why. I am not a programmer by trade so likely doing something dumb.

Can anyone advise please? I look forward to condescending comments :-)

```
001 # Find and replace in multiple word docs
002 # Usage: Open in ISE, update the $folderPath, change the find/replace fields in the $textToReplace array, click the run button.
003 
004 $folderPath = "C:\Users\tim.handy\Desktop\testchangecontentsword\STANDARD  DATA - Copy\CHEMICAL\ANALYSIS\01 Pre-treatment incl strippers\*" # multi-folders: "C:\fso1*", "C:\fso2*"
005 $fileType = "*.doc"           # *.doc will take all .doc* files, i.e .docx also
006 $passwd = Read-Host("Type in the password:")
007 
008 $textToReplace = @{
009 # "TextToFind" = "TextToReplaceWith" and it's case sensitive.
010 "Bath 01800" = "yay"
011 }
012 
013 $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
014 $word.Visible = $false
015 
016 #region Find/Replace parameters
017 $matchCase = $true
018 $matchWholeWord = $true
019 $matchWildcards = $false
020 $matchSoundsLike = $false
021 $matchAllWordForms = $false
022 $forward = $true
023 $findWrap = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue
024 $format = $false
025 $replace = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace]::wdReplaceOne
026 #endregion
027 
028 $countf = 0 #count files
029 $countr = 0 #count replacements per file
030 $counta = 0 #count all replacements
031 
032 Function findAndReplace($objFind, $FindText, $ReplaceWith) {
033     #simple Find and Replace to execute on a Find object
034     #we let the function return (True/False) to count the replacements
035     $objFind.Execute($FindText, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, $matchWildCards, $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, $forward, $findWrap, $format, $ReplaceWith, $replace) #> $null
036 }
037 
038 Function findAndReplaceAll($objFind, $FindText, $ReplaceWith) {
039     #make sure we replace all occurrences (while we find a match)
040     $count = 0
041     $count += findAndReplace $objFind $FindText $ReplaceWith
042     While ($objFind.Found) {
043         $count += findAndReplace $objFind $FindText $ReplaceWith
044     }
045     return $count
046 }
047 
048 Function findAndReplaceMultiple($objFind, $lookupTable) {
049     #apply multiple Find and Replace on the same Find object
050     $count = 0
051     $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
052         $count += findAndReplaceAll $objFind $_.Key $_.Value
053     }
054     return $count
055 }
056 
057 Function findAndReplaceWholeDoc($Document, $lookupTable) {
058     $count = 0
059     # Loop through each StoryRange
060     ForEach ($storyRge in $Document.StoryRanges) {
061         Do {
062             $count += findAndReplaceMultiple $storyRge.Find $lookupTable
063             #check for linked Ranges
064             $storyRge = $storyRge.NextStoryRange
065         } Until (!$storyRge) #null is False
066 
067     }
068     #region Loop through Shapes within Headers and Footers
069     # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/shapes-object-word
070     # "The Count property for this collection in a document returns the number of items in the main story only.
071     #  To count the shapes in all the headers and footers, use the Shapes collection with any HeaderFooter object."
072     # Hence the .Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1) which should be able to collect all Shapes, without the need
073     # for looping through each Section.
074     #endregion
075     $shapes = $Document.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Shapes
076     If ($shapes.Count) {
077         #ForEach ($shape in $shapes | Where {$_.TextFrame.HasText -eq -1}) {
078         ForEach ($shape in $shapes | Where {[bool]$_.TextFrame.HasText}) {
079             #Write-Host $($shape.TextFrame.HasText)
080             $count += findAndReplaceMultiple $shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find $lookupTable
081         }
082     }
083     return $count
084 }
085 
086 Function processDoc ($pass) {
087     $doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName, $null, $false, $null, $pass, $null, $null, $pass)
088     $count = findAndReplaceWholeDoc $doc $textToReplace
089     $doc.Close([ref]$true)
090     return $count
091 }
092 
093 $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
094 Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Recurse -Filter $fileType | ForEach-Object { 
095   Write-Host "Processing \`"$($_.Name)\`"..."
096   $countr = processDoc($passwd)
097   Write-Host "$countr replacements made."
098   $counta += $countr
099   $countf++
100 }
101 $sw.Stop()
102 $elapsed = $sw.Elapsed.toString()
103 Write-Host "`nDone. $countf files processed in $elapsed"
104 Write-Host "$counta replacements made in total."
105 
106 $word.Quit()
107 $word = $null
108 [gc]::collect() 
109 [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Do you know what *kind* of protection you're trying to lift? You're providing two passwords... Do you get a message? What is it? Which line causes it?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your assistance. My knowledge of Word protection is limited to that it's password protected for editing, not opening. I provided two passwords just because there were several password options in the available parameters. Error states: "Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "asdf" value of type "string" to type "Object". At line:87 char:5"  'asdf' was the password I supplied from line 6.

Comment: If it's protected for editing then you should be able to open it without a password. If you try to open it as a user can you open it without being prompted? If yes, then you need to enter the password after the document is open, but before I confuse the issue with code, let's make sure where we're at. If you are prompted for a password when opening, what's the title and message of the prompt?

Comment: @cindymeister aha, yes, they all open without the password, but then have to be unprotected with a password before allowing to edit. Would the edit password need to go somewhere in the findAndReplace function somehow?

Comment: Yes. I don't use powershell, so I'm guessing about the correct syntax, but something like: ` If ($Document:ProtectionType != wdNoProtection) {$Document .Unprotect ("password") } and to protect it again use $Document.Protect. This will require a parameter for the protection TYPE, but we don't know which kind has been used on this document so you have to find that out.

Comment: thank you @CindyMeister, I'll have a look into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution...

```
Function processDoc {
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName)

# I added this bit
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-unprotect-method-word
# Check for file protection
If ($doc.ProtectionType -and ($doc.ProtectionType -ne 'wdNoProtection') ) {
    # Unprotect file with password
    if ($doc.Unprotect) {
        $doc.Unprotect($FilePassword)
    } 
} 

$count = findAndReplaceWholeDoc $doc $textToReplace

# I added this bit
# Reprotect file with 'wdAllowOnlyReading'
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdprotectiontype-enumeration-word
$doc.Protect(3, $null, $FilePassword)

$doc.Close([ref]$true)
return $count
```

}

Thanks @cindymeister